# How to integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ using substitution?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

How you integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ using following substitution? $1+x^2=t$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=\sqrt{t-1} \Rightarrow dx = \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t-1}}dt$... Now I'm stuck. I don't know how to proceed using substitution rule.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea to proceed?

Comment: $1+x^2=t\implies 2xdx=dt\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2x}$

Comment: @Belgi that's the same results alvoutilla found, just written in different letters.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have $dt$ twice in the expression for $dx$?

Comment: @KevinCarlson - indeed, but I wanted to show to the PO that he doesn't need to first 'solve' for $x$ to get that

Comment: @Belgi, OK, I see.

Comment: I know this can be integrated more easily when you know that $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx = sinh^{-1}x$. What about integration of $\int \sqrt{3x-2}dx$?

Comment: @alvoutila The substitution $t=3x-2$ (and $dt=3dx$) seems natural for this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By the substitution you suggested you get
$$
\int \frac1{2\sqrt{t(t-1)}} \,dt=
\int \frac1{\sqrt{4t^2-4t}} \,dt=
\int \frac1{\sqrt{(2t-1)^2-1}} \,dt
$$
Now the substitution $u=2t-1$ seems reasonable.

---

However your original integral can also be solved by
$x=\sinh t$ and $dx=\cosh t\, dt$ which gives
$$\int \frac{\cosh t}{\cosh t} \, dt = \int 1\, dt=t=\operatorname{arcsinh} x = \ln (x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+C,$$
since $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 t}=\cosh t$.

See [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and their inverses.

If you are familiar (=used to manipulate) with the hyperbolic functions then $x=a\sinh t$ is worth trying whenever you see the expression $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$ in your integral ($a$ being an arbitrary constant).

Comment: How do you get from $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$ to $\int \frac{1}{cosh t}dx=\int \frac{cosh t}{cosh t}dt$?

Comment: @alvoutila $\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 t}=\cosh t$. (I've added this to my post, too.)

Comment: Instead of using hyperbolic functions, if you use normal trig functions (e.g. x = sin(t)), then you end up with integral = arcsin(x). Why is this incorrect?   EDIT: NEVERMIND... 1 + sin**2 =/= cos

Comment: @user60462 As shown in other answers, you can use trigonometric substitution with $x=\tan t$.

Comment: Whats cosh different that cos?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter The Wikipedia article [Hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions) is linked in the answer - it contains some information about $\cosh x$, $\sinh x$ and some other related functions.

Answer (score 14):

A variant of the hyperbolic function substitution is to let $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)$. Note that $1+x^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(t^2+2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$.

So $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)$.  That was the whole point of the substitution, it is a *rationalizing substitution* that makes the square root simple. Also, $dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\,dt$.

Carry out the substitution. "Miraculously," our integral simplifies to $\int \frac{dt}{t}$.

Answer (score 6):

Put $x=\tan y$, so that $dx=\sec^2y \ dy$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sec y$

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{\sec^2y \ dy}{\sec y}$$

$$=\int \sec y\, dy$$

which evaluates to $\displaystyle\ln|\sec y+\tan y|+ C$ , applying the standard formula whose proof is [here](http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/sec.htm)  and $C$ is an indeterminate constant for any indefinite integral.

$$=\ln|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x| + C$$

We can substitute $x$ with $a \sec y$ for $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$, and with $a \sin y$ for $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{1+x^2}}$$

Let, $x = \tan\theta$

$dx = \sec^{2}\theta{d\theta}$

substitute, $x$, $dx$

$$A=\int\left(\frac{1}{\sec\theta}\right){\sec^{2}\theta{d\theta}}$$

$$A=\int{\sec\theta{d\theta}}$$

$$A=\int{\sec\theta\left(\frac{\sec\theta + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta + \tan\theta}\right){d\theta}}$$

$$A=\int{\left(\frac{\sec^2\theta + \sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sec\theta + \tan\theta}\right){d\theta}}$$

Let, $(\sec\theta + \tan\theta) = u$

$(\sec^2\theta + \sec\theta\tan\theta)d\theta = du$

$$A=\int\frac{du}{u}$$

$$A=\ln{u}+c$$

$$A=\ln{\vert\sec\theta + \tan\theta\vert}+c$$

$$A=\ln{\vert\sqrt[]{1+\tan^2\theta} + \tan\theta\vert}+c$$

$A=\ln{\vert\sqrt[]{1+x^2} + x\vert}+c$, where $c$ is a constant