# Solving the integral $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

I need to solve

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

but I'm nowhere near the solution. I tried substituting

$u = x^2 + 1$

such that $dx = \frac{1}{2x}$
yielding
$$\int u^{-1/2} du = \frac{1}{2x}\frac{u^{1/2}}{1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{x} =\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$$

but this is nothing near the solution of

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = ln|\sqrt{x^2+1}+x|+C$$

Comment: Try $\;x=\sinh u\;$ ....

Comment: See e.g. [How to integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ using substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179129/how-to-integrate-frac1-sqrt1x2-using-substitution)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$x=\tan(t)$$ then we get $$x^2+1=\tan^2(t)+1=\frac{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}$$
and $$dx=(\tan^2(t)+1)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the trigonometric substitution $x(\theta)=\tan{\theta}$:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx=
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{[x(\theta)]^2+1}}x'(\theta)\,d\theta=\\
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan^2{\theta}+1}}\sec^2{\theta}\,d\theta=
\int\frac{\sec^2{\theta}}{\sqrt{\sec^2{\theta}}}\,d\theta=\\
\int\frac{\sec^2{\theta}}{|\sec{\theta}|}\,d\theta.
$$

Here, $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ because on that interval $\tan\theta$ gives you the entire real line and $\sec{\theta}\ge 1$ there. Therefore, $|\sec\theta|=\sec\theta$:

$$
\int\frac{\sec^2{\theta}}{|\sec{\theta}|}\,d\theta=
\int\frac{\sec^2{\theta}}{\sec{\theta}}\,d\theta=
\int\sec{\theta}\,d\theta.
$$

Now just use the following fact:
$$\int\sec{x}\,dx=\ln{|\tan{x}+\sec{x}|}+C.$$

Comment: For anyone curious, the fact that $\int \sec x\, dx = \ln \left| \tan x + \sec x\right|+C$ is proved here: [How do I integrate $\sec(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506780/how-do-i-integrate-secx)